# Magento 2 Show customer attribute in ui_component form

Tags: magento2, attributes, uicomponent, customer-account, ui-form

I've created **ui_component** form where I need to show customer details, same as **Customer Edit**.

But, I am able to show their data from **`customer_entity`** table.

> **`DataProvider.php`**

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    
    // {Vendor}\{Module}\Model\GridFactory 
    // Returns Customer Resource Model
    $items = $this->gridFactory->create()->getCollection();
    
   $items->getSelect()->join('customer_entity_text as second', 'main_table.entity_id = second.entity_id');
    //print_r($items->getData()); exit;
    foreach($items as $contact){
        $this->loadedData[$contact->getEntityId()]['contact'] = $contact->getData();
    }
    
    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

> I've joined **`customer_entity_text`** table with my Factory in order to display `status` (Customer Attribute).
>
> Now My Second attribute is `file` type. It's in **`customer_entity_varchar`**, Firstly I thought of adding another join but I think it's not the good way.

So, Is there any solution for this? I need to display both **`Customer Attributes`** in my form.

> ui_component

```
<field name="value">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Status</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

1). Above component is working good for **Status** but not for **Profile Image** that is Image type.

```
<field name="value">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Profile Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="path_controller"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

**Even if I remove one field with same name `form element` it doesn't seem to be working.**

Take a look at **`field`** name that is **`value`** for **Status**.

If I use the same thing for **image** field then image component disappears.

**Note**: I've no idea why Magento doesn't allow to use the name as **`value`**.

> Cause I've joined in the collection so i am getting `value` as the array key.

**Question: How can I get customer attributes in this form without join in the collection ?

Also if you have other solution then most welcome.**

Comment: Can you check if the new attribute(s) you're using are in the Default attribute set of customer entity ?

Comment: Could you read your own question again: the question does not make sense to me when reading it. And therefore it does not help us to resolve your issue?

Comment: Forget rest of things, If you can than answer for how can i display customer attributes in my custom ui form ? one is with Image and other one is text.

Comment: is your question to build a form in the frontend or backend?

Answer (score 1):

In DataProvider.php to change

From

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    
    // {Vendor}\{Module}\Model\GridFactory 
    // Returns Customer Resource Model
    $items = $this->gridFactory->create()->getCollection();
    
   $items->getSelect()->join('customer_entity_text as second', 'main_table.entity_id = second.entity_id');
    //print_r($items->getData()); exit;
    foreach($items as $contact){
        $this->loadedData[$contact->getEntityId()]['contact'] = $contact->getData();
    }
    
    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

To

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    
    // {Vendor}\{Module}\Model\GridFactory 
    // Returns Customer Resource Model
    $items = $this->gridFactory->create()->getCollection();
    
   $items->joinAttribute(
            'status',
            'customer/status',
            '',
            null,
            'left'
        );
   $items->joinAttribute(
            'profile_image',
            'customer/profile_image',
            '',
            null,
            'left'
        );
    foreach($items as $contact){
        $this->loadedData[$contact->getEntityId()]['contact'] = $contact->getData();
    }
    
    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom table with the relationship of **customer_entity** table using setup script as follows:

```
$relationalTable = 'custom_table';  
$table = $setup->getConnection()
    ->newTable($setup->getTable($relationalTable))
    // --- Add your other columns here ---
    ->addColumn('customer_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true],
            'Customer Id')
    ->addForeignKey(
        $setup->getFkName(
            $relationalTable,           // priTableName
            'customer_id',              // priColumnName
            'customer_entity',          // refTableName
            'entity_id'                 // refColumnName
        ),
        'customer_id',                  // column
        $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),    
        'entity_id',                    // refColumn
        Table::ACTION_CASCADE           // onDelete
    )
    ->setComment('Customer relation table');

$setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

Then you need to load customer model and join your custom table in getData() function of DataProvider.php as follows:

```
protected $_customerModel;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerModel
) {
    $this->_customerModel = $customerModel;
}

public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

   $customer = $this->_customerModel->create();
    $collection = $customer->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        ['custom' => $this->_resource->getTableName('custom_table')],
        'e.entity_id = custom.customer_id'
    );

    foreach($collection as $item){
        $this->loadedData[$item->getId()]['contact'] = $item->getData();
        // Using $item->getData(), you can get customer object with custom attributes as $item->getStatus() or $item->getProfileImage()
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

Now you can use field names in ui_component as follows:

```
<field name="status"> <!-- your custom attribute code as field name -->
...
</field>

<field name="profile_image"> <!-- your custom attribute code as field name -->
...
</field>
```

Hope this solution may resolve your issue.

Comment: I need help please go through my question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257577/magento2-how-to-remove-choose-an-option-in-configurable-products-drop-down/258144?noredirect=1#comment363515_258144"